# Remove Duplicate from 2D array or Matrix

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I have 2D array below

```
5.0 5.0 100 99 
5.5 5.5 101 100 
6.0 6.0 102 101
```

I want the expected output below

```
5.0 100 99 
5.5 101 100  
6.0 102 101
```

What I'd tried, I have passed the 1D array to my custom function which will convert 1d to 2D array, the final output is `finalArr`, which I further pass to `stream` function and map as list and find the ditinct

```
String finalArr[][] = convert1DTo2DArray(arr3, 3, 4);

Arrays.stream(finalArr)
        .map(Arrays::asList)
        .distinct()
        .forEach(row -> System.out.printf("%-3s%-7s%s\n", row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)));
```

Output:

```
5.05.0    100
5.55.5    101
6.06.0    102
```

After some workaround, I've managed to get

```
5.0 100 99 
5.5 101 100  
6.0 102 101
```

by this code :

```
 Arrays.stream(finalArr)
             .map(Arrays::asList)
             .distinct()
             .forEach(row -> System.out.printf("%-5s%-7s%s\n", row.get(1), row.get(2), row.get(3)));
```

Now I want to collect it as 2D array, is there any better approach for the same, kindly suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `distinct()` for each array, you can solve your problem using :

```
String[][] result = Arrays.stream(finalArr)
        .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s).distinct().toArray(String[]::new))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

**Outputs**

```
[[5.0, 100, 99], [5.5, 101, 100], [6.0, 102, 101]]
```